# Prevent html5 video

Tags: html, video, safari

I'm having trouble with a video I'm using as a background -- it works correctly on firefox & chrome, however on Safari on load and when it loops, it flashes black for a moment.

Because it's looping the trick of having it fade in after won't work. I'm not really sure what's causing the issue. It's using a poster which loads correctly. the file is about 1.1mb.

Any ideas or solutions?

```
<video id="HeroVideo2" class="width100" loop="true" autoplay="true" preload="none" poster="/assets/videoposter.jpg">
  <source src="/assets/hero.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="/assets/hero.webm" type="video/webm">
  <source src="/assets/her.ogv" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by 'flashes back'? Also if you can provide a link to the video that would help.

Comment: Hi There -- I actually just found what was causing the issue for me -- I've been doing the encoding in Handbrake, I had forgotten to check check the "Optimise for web" option. I re-encoded it with this option and the issue resolved. 

By black flashing i meant that when it was loading in Safari it would show 1 or two frames of black on load and when looping.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that the issue was related to encoding in Handbrake.

I reencoded the video and made sure to check the "Web optimised" option and the new video no longer has the one or two back frames when viewed in Safari.